# Multiple Spring @RequestMapping headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, request-mapping

my question is very simple, It's possibily use two different content-type headers on the same method?

like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/provider", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json,content-type=multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<String> createProviderQuote(
            @RequestParam(value = "work", required = true) String workId,
            UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request) {
}
```

I need to send a Json Object with Images (Multipart Files), but I have not succeeded. For that reason I use headers:

```
headers = "Accept=application/json,content-type=multipart/form-data"
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - for setting what your endpoint will accept and return you need to use `consumes` and `produces` attributes od `@RequestMapping` annotation like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/provider", 
                method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
```

Of course then you need to properly support this on frontend side due to your requirements